# Construct File Object Disabling ".."

Tags: java, file

In Java, can a File object be constructed that does not permit the use of ".." in the child argument? Is there some way to quote the second arg so that ".." doesn't work, or some other command for constructing File objects in that way?

For example, user input could specify an ID. That ID could then be used to open a file.

```
File f = new File(PARENT, id);
```

Depending on other parameters from the user, the next command may be:

```
f.delete();
```

One malicious action from a user could be to enter "../../some-important-file" for id.

"id" could seemingly be sanitized, or some function could be used to verify that "id" is in fact a valid ID (which would, e.g., not be valid if it starts with "../"), rather than constructing a File directly from user input, but I am curious if there is a way to construct a File in the manner I described (without permitting "..").

Thanks.

Comment: Two manual ways to do this would be to 1) check that the parent of f is PARENT, or 2) loop through children of PARENT and return the one that matches id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do what you want without encoding the check yourself in one form or another.

If your aim is just to claim academically claim you have used only a constructor, then you can extend `File` and provide a constructor yourself. For instance:

```
class SafeFile extends File {
   SafeFile(File parent, String child) throws SecurityException {
      super(parent,child);
      try {
         if(!getCanonicalPath().startsWith(parent.getCanonicalPath()))
            throw new SecurityException(child+" is above the designated directory");
      } catch(IOException e) {
         throw new SecurityException("Cannot confirm safety");
      }
   }
}
```

Which should only allow `File f = new SafeFile(PARENT,id);` (assuming  `PARENT` is a `File`) to work whenever the file's path begins with it's parents path, i.e. it is in `PARENT` or some sub-directory.

The exact way you check and handle these matters depends on what you restrictions precisely you're aiming to impose, on whether or not you are okay with terminate in a run-time exception for bad input.